# Pentaho Kettle - How to get all child nodes in XML file

Tags: xml, xpath, pentaho, kettle

I have an xml file that I'm trying to insert into MongoDB using Pentaho Kettle.    This is a sample node I am processing.

```
<LearningStandardItem RefId="ac4fc887aeef497198822bd233989505" xml:lang="en">
  <StandardHierarchyLevel HierarchyLevelDescription="Level 1">1</StandardHierarchyLevel>
  <ParentItemRefId>ac4fc887aeef497198822bd233989505</ParentItemRefId>
  <StatementCode>LAFS.K12.L</StatementCode>
  <Statement><![CDATA[Language]]></Statement>
  <GradeLevels>
    <GradeLevel Code="KG"/>
    <GradeLevel Code="01"/>
    <GradeLevel Code="02"/>
    <GradeLevel Code="03"/>
    <GradeLevel Code="04"/>
    <GradeLevel Code="05"/>
    <GradeLevel Code="06"/>
    <GradeLevel Code="07"/>
    <GradeLevel Code="08"/>
    <GradeLevel Code="09"/>
    <GradeLevel Code="10"/>
    <GradeLevel Code="11"/>
    <GradeLevel Code="12"/>
  </GradeLevels>
  <SubjectArea Code="10">Language Arts</SubjectArea>
  <LearningStandardDocumentRefId>48c8286c12424beb950194015407afa5</LearningStandardDocumentRefId>
  <SIF_ExtendedElements>
    <SIF_ExtendedElement Name="CCRefId"><![CDATA[CED36FDE-67AD-11DF-AB5F-995D9DFF4B22]]></SIF_ExtendedElement>
  </SIF_ExtendedElements>
</LearningStandardItem>
```

If I set my Loop XPath to /AB_SIF/LearningStandardItem, then I get all the nodes I want except that I'm trying to get all grade levels.  When I set a field to GradeLevel/@Code, I only get the first GradeLevel node.  I need to get them all.  I am trying to insert all the grade levels into an array in MongoDB.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It returns all Code as you want.

```
/LearningStandardItem/GradeLevels/GradeLevel/@Code
```

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: What screen in Pentaho are you using to test the XPath expression?

Comment: I know the xpath works in general but it only returns the first node in Pentaho when using Get XML from file. I'm trying to get all nodes in Pentaho.

Comment: Looks like the issue is in pentaho :(

Comment: "Loop XPath" will generate stream. It is actually set the xml context for xpath expression in "Fields" tab . If Loop XPath refer to single element "//LearningStandardItem" then u will get single row in stream, else if u refer "//GradeLevel" then u will get 13 rows in stream, and u can extract value from each row in "Fields" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps in PDI *(Step: Get Data from XML)*:

1. Set the XPATH to `/LearningStandardItem/GradeLevels//*`

[image]

2. In the getFields section of the step, set the XPATH as `@Code` and the Element type = `Attribute`.

[image]

this will fetch you all the attributes inside the GradeLevel node. I have attached a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/rishuatgithub/6cf87e1600d140d10b74).

[image]

Alternatively, you can also try with step "XML Input Stream (StAX)" in PDI. It uses StAX parser to read all the xml nodes and attributes. It becomes useful in case of large xml file.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Doing it this way does get me all GradeLevel nodes but then I'm not able to get the values of the other nodes like StatementCode, Statement, etc.  I need to be able to get the values of all nodes as well as all the GradeLevel nodes or come up with a way to get these separately and then merge them back.